# D3 - Line chart, dont show line when no values

Tags: d3.js

I have a stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-no-line-points-nm1jzs?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts&hideNavigation=1

I have a stack bar chart with line chart on top.

The x-axis shows months, I want to show all the months on this axis but I won't have data for the months to come.

On the stacked chart I can just have 0 (zero) values and the bars don't show but how can I stop the line chart from showing in months where there are no values.

I don't want to have 0 (zero) like in the example.

Comment: set there value to `null`

Comment: at least for plain d3 should work, https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/0533f44f2cfabecc5e3a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [line.defined](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#line_defined) and using [bl.ocks](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/0533f44f2cfabecc5e3a) as an example reference, here's the change in your case:

1. Line fn:

   ```
   var valueline = d3.line()
      .defined(function (d) { return d.value; })
   ```
2. Circles with filtered data:

   ```
   this.lineArea.selectAll("line-circle")
      .data(linedata.filter(function(d) { return d.value; }))
   ```

Here's the fork:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-no-line-points-zcqa1c?file=src/app/bar-chart.ts